# Unable to access .asmx from jquery from .aspx page

Tags: jquery, web-services

I have a solution file in C# which has a .asmx page , i am trying to access a method of that service from jQuery, it works fine in local machine but is failing on the server.

I have looked on a similar kind of example in the portal but it did not help.
Any leads will be helpful.

Below is the jquery code:

```
var Partarr = txtPartVAL.split("\n");            
                var sCFGlst;
                    for (var i = 0; i < Partarr.length; i++) {

                        var pageUrl = '<%=ResolveUrl("~/AutoCompleteList.asmx")%>'
                        $.ajax({
                            type: "POST",
                            //url: pageUrl + "AutoCompleteList.asmx/LookupPartListForListBox",
                            url: pageUrl + "/LookupPartListForListBox",
                            data: { partNumber: Partarr[i] }, 
                             dataType: "xml",
                            async: true,
                            success: function (data) {

                             sCFGlst = $(data).find('string').text();

                                addParttoList(sCFGlst);                          
                            },
                            error: function (err) {
                                alert('hi');
                                console.log(err);
                            }
                        });
                    }

Web service code :

      [WebMethod]
            public string LookupPartListForListBox(string partNumber)
            {
                configuration = new DitConfiguration();
                dataService = new TamService(configuration);
                presenter = new AutoCompleteListPresenter(dataService, bomService);
                string partList = presenter.ShowPartListForPartListBox(partNumber);
                return partList;
            }
```

The Same code piece i am deploying on the server.
Added the jquery reference.

Thanks
PG

Comment: where is your .asmx file? is it in the root directory?

Comment: it means path is such that `ResolveUrl` fails to render it in server.